# values turning into empty strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When i visualise my code with python tutor the values of the array become empty strings this happens when the if condition is precessed and i don't understand why does it happen. can someone please explain why is this happening and provide a fix for it ?

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int countWords(char *src, char toFind)
{
    int numWords;
    int i;
    int d;

    numWords = 0;
    i = 0;
    d = 0;

    while (*src)
    {

      if (*src =! (toFind)) //it happens here*?*
        numwords++;

      src++;
    }  

}

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "abc,ffg,ijk";
    char c = ',';
    int res = 0;
    char *ptr;

    ptr = arr;

    res = countWords(ptr,c);

    printf("%d", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are not returning any value in `countWords`. Use `return numWords;`

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo, if you wanted a comparison, you should have used `!=` instead of `=!` which is two operator and tells the compiler to evaluate the variable and assign the reverse result to `*src`.

Also, you may have used the wrong operator assuming you wanted the word count and not character count. Using `==` will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgot to add a `return` at the end of your function `countWords`

```c
return (numwords);
```

as SaltyPleb said, i imagine that your function returns the number of words to find, you should change `!=` by `==`.